# How to 'setTimeout' on a <div> to automatically go to another <div>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a site using a photo slider like http://www.queness.com/resources/html/scroll/horizontal.html and here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/EXfnN/1/

I'd like the last/third div which is **div id="item3"** to show up about 3 seconds and the screen will **automatically** go back to the first div again which is **div id="item1"** without any click function on the third div, and then I can view any page again like before.

How can I setTimeout on a div rather than a page? Any code/direction is appreciated.

Thanks very much.
S:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the `onAfter` event of the `scrollTo` plugin..

update of your code that make the scroll

```
$('#wrapper').scrollTo($(this).attr('href'), 800,{
            onAfter: function(id){
                if (id === '#item3'){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $(id).find('.panel').click();
                    }, 3000);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: @Dror, thanks .. i had made one while testing the answer, but forgot to post it ..

Comment: Thanks Gaby and Dror, great help! Thank you, S:)